# Is there a way to make all specified object properties required in jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema

Let's say I have an object specification like this,

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "number" },
        "bar": { "type": "number" }
    }
    "required": [ "foo", "bar" ]
}
```

Is there a simple way to write the last line that doesn't require repeating all properties? I'm thinking of something like writing, `"required": "all"`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all properties must be repeated in required.

From the specification of required keyword (draft-04):

> The value of this keyword MUST be an array. This array MUST have at
>   least one element. Elements of this array MUST be strings, and MUST be
>   unique.

…leaving no room for patterns or such.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, we will need to repeat all the mandatory property names under required. 
Else even more cumbersome way would be to repeat it at field level,

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "number", "required":true },
        "bar": { "type": "number", "required":true }
    }    
}
```